# HowTo rewrite subdomain to apache userdir

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-userdir

As described in [this blog](http://cjmaclachlan.blogspot.de/2008/02/modrewrite-moduserdir-subdomains-and.html)  I want to rewrite internally

```
http://xy.user.phpfarm.lan -> http://user.phpfarm.lan/~xy/
```

Module userdir is enabled.

With the following Apache2 vhost config file, it has got a bug:

**/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/phpfarm:**

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
 ServerAdmin root@localhost
 ServerName em-sv-phpfarm.lan
 ServerAlias *.user.phpfarm.lan user.phpfarm.lan phpfarm.lan

 DocumentRoot /var/www/
 <Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
 <Directory /var/www>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride None
  Order allow,deny
  allow from all
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 LogLevel warn

 CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

 RewriteLog "/tmp/rewrites"
 RewriteLogLevel 5
 # Uncomment the above two lines and watch /tmp for some debug info.

 RewriteEngine On

 # Make bob.user.phpfarm.em.lan be treated as user.phpfarm.lan/~bob
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.user\.phpfarm\.lan$ [NC]
 # In the above line make sure you escape (preceed with a backslash) every period (.) in the address.
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[^/]+/~.*$
 # exclude file handler
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/php-fcgi/.*$
 RewriteRule ^/([^~]+) /~%1/$1 [PT,L]
</virtualhost>
```

- http://xy.user.phpfarm.lan lists an index of /var/www, but it should list an index of /home/xy/public_html, that is wrong
- http://xy.user.phpfarm.lan/testfile shows the content of /home/xy/public_html/testfile, that is correct!

So I think an empty REQUEST_URI isn't captured correctly. But I can't find the bug. Does anybody know, why?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the last line with

```
 RewriteRule ^/([^~]*) /~%1/$1 [PT,L]
```

You were insisting on at least one character after the slash, so cases where `REQUEST_URI` was `/` were being ignored.

Answer (score -2):

Oh be the way:
You have to change `AllowOverride None`  to `AllowOverride All`